# Break up A Single TextView into Different line

Tags: java, android

I need to get the information transfered from the NFC READER  to my phone to be Arrange in each line wth for eg.Event ID,Event Name,DateTime,Venue.

At the moment when I tap my phone to the reader using my android app,all i get is a string of text.I want to break the text to be able to identify Event Id,EventName,DateTime,Venue to be able to getText seperately for each text to submit to database.

here is my code

```
package com.techblogon.loginexample;



import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Arrays;

import com.techblogon.loginexample.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.NfcEvent;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter.CreateNdefMessageCallback;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter.OnNdefPushCompleteCallback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UserScreen extends Activity implements CreateNdefMessageCallback, OnNdefPushCompleteCallback{

    private static final int MESSAGE_SENT = 1;
    NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
    TextView mInfoText;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.userscreen);
        mInfoText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        // Check for available NFC Adapter
        mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
            mInfoText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            mInfoText.setText("NFC is not available on this device.");
        }
        // Register callback to set NDEF message
        mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(this, this);
        // Register callback to listen for message-sent success
        mNfcAdapter.setOnNdefPushCompleteCallback(this, this);
    } @Override
    public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent event) {
        Time time = new Time();
        time.setToNow();
        String text = ("Beam me up!\n\n" +
                "Beam Time: " + time.format("%H:%M:%S"));
        NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(
              new NdefRecord[] { createMimeRecord("application/com.example.android.beam", text.getBytes()) });
        return msg;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNdefPushComplete(NfcEvent arg0) {
        // A handler is needed to send messages to the activity when this
        // callback occurs, because it happens from a binder thread
        mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_SENT).sendToTarget();        
        Log.w ("Sent",mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_SENT).toString());
    }
    /** This handler receives a message from onNdefPushComplete */
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_SENT:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Check to see that the Activity started due to an Android Beam
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
            processIntent(getIntent());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        // onResume gets called after this to handle the intent
        setIntent(intent);
    }

    // Parses the NDEF Message from the intent and prints to the TextView

   void processIntent(Intent intent) {      
       Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(
               NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
       // only one message sent during the beam 
       NdefMessage msg = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[0];
       // record 0 contains the MIME type, record 1 is the AAR, if present
       mInfoText.setText(new String(msg.getRecords()[0].getPayload())); 


   }


   public NdefRecord createMimeRecord(String mimeType, byte[] payload) {
       byte[] mimeBytes = mimeType.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
       NdefRecord mimeRecord = new NdefRecord(
               NdefRecord.TNF_MIME_MEDIA, mimeBytes, new byte[0], payload);
       return mimeRecord;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       // If NFC is not available, we won't be needing this menu
       if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
           return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
       }
       MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
           case R.id.menu_settings:
               Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NFCSHARING_SETTINGS);
               startActivity(intent);
               return true;
           default:
               return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
   }
    }
```

Comment: What are you getting in the string? It seems you are getting appended values and you want to extract each one separately.Explain it.

Comment: The String that I am getting is an NDEF Message from the NFC Reader which is communicating in P2P mode with my Android App.

From the public void onNewINtent Method,I am getting the Ndef Message and Converting it to String to display on a textView as a straight line.I want to break up such that I can identify the String that I break up for eg(1 CCN DAY 12.30pm Mensa) to 
(1 String[1]
CCN DAY String[2]
12.30pm String[3]
Mensa String[4]) excluding the bracket.

Abel to identify each line as a string to be able to send it to the Database for each column through Web Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

`textView.setText(string1+System.getProperty ("line.separator")+string2);`

**Edit** : Take two string variable like

```
String string1 = "Hello";
String string2 = "Android";
```

then

```
your_textView.setText(string1 + System.getProperty ("line.separator") + string2);
```

OR

```
your_textView.setText("Hello" + System.getProperty ("line.separator") + "Android");
```

Comment: The String 1 and String 2 is from what variable?